# ModelState: more information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate

My ModelState.IsValid is returning false, but I cannot work out why the validation is failing. I have no data annotations on any of the properties of the view model so don't understand.

How do I determine what is making the validation fail? I think only then will I be able to work out what is going on.

Comment: Anything which is a value type, say int, is automatically considered required.  The same with DateTime.  Are you submitting with any empty properties?

Answer (score 2):

Besides the data annotations, errors can be introduced by simple binding issues: a value that's supposed to be a number, but which has letters in it, for example.

The [`ModelState.Errors` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.errors(v=vs.118).aspx) has a collection of error information that you can inspect or iterate across to discover which properties have errors, and what error messages were produced for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch errors using :

```
foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values) {
    foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
    {        
    // put debug point or add all the errors in collection or list  
    }
}
```